# why does proving "If A or B, then C" require us to prove (1) "if A, then C" and also (2) "if B, then C"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

The following is the truth table for ((A ∨ B) → C)

[image]

The statement is false only when the hypothesis (A ∨ B) is true but conclusion C is false. And just at least A or B being true is sufficient for the hypothesis to be true. As such, why is not enough to prove only one of (1) or (2)?

Comment: This works for the other direction only: $((A\vee B)\to C)\leftrightarrow((A\to C)\wedge(B\to C))$. If you only know $A\to C$, then you can't say "either one of $A$ or $B$ is enough to prove $C$."

A good way to summarize this is that "$(A\vee B)\to C$" is *stronger* than just "$A\to C$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you prove "If $A$ then $C$". Consider the case where $A$ is false, $B$ is true, and $C$ is also false.

Clearly, "If $A$ then $C$" holds. But it does not hold that "If $A \lor B$ then $C$".

Answer (score 3):

In layman's terms, proving that something occurs whenever at least one of some conditions is true means proving that each of said conditions is sufficient.

In terms of connectives, \begin{align}(A\lor B)\to C&\equiv C\lor \neg(A\lor B)\equiv C\lor (\neg A\land \neg B)\equiv (C\lor \neg A)\land (C\lor \neg B)\equiv\\&\equiv (A\to C)\land (B\to C)\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

(Posted after a previous answer was accepted.)

> Why does proving "If A or B, then C" require us to prove (1) "if A,
> then C" and also (2) "if B, then C"?

I think the truth table you want is:

[image]

This is the logic underlying the method of proof by cases. Here, there are are two cases to consider: $A$ or $B$

This principle can also be more usefully stated for two cases as:

[image]

Here is a formal proof using a form of natural deduction (screenshot from my proof checker, '|' = OR):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume "If $A$ or $B$ then $C$" is true. Now:

- Assume $A$ is true. Can we conclude that $C$ is true?
- Assume $B$ is true. Can we conclude that $C$ is true?

From this we can conclude that the statement "If $A$ or $B$ then $C$" implies both "If $A$ then $C$" and "If $B$ then $C$".

Going the other way, assume both "If $A$ then $C$" and "If $B$ then $C$" are true. Now assume $A$ or $B$. Can we conclude $C$? From this we may conclude that "If $A$ then $C$" and "If $B$ then $C$" together imply "If $A$ or $B$ then $C$".

From all of this we can conclude that "If $A$ or $B$ then $C$" is logically equivalent to the conjunction of "If $A$ then $C$" and "If $B$ then $C$". And usually the conjunction is easier to prove. It's always a little finicky to handle disjunctions in the antecedent.

---

Maybe a concrete example can help a little. Assume the following statement:

> If I win the lottery or I inherit a lot of money, then I will buy a new house.

It's quite clear that if I win the lottery, I will buy a new house. Also, it is quite clear that if I inherit a lot of money, I will buy a new house.

Next, consider the following:

> If I win the lottery, then I will buy a new house. Also, if I inherit a lot of money, then I will buy a new house.

It is quite clear that if I either win the lottery or inherit a lot of money, I am going to buy a new house.

---

Finally, for the boringly dry solution: Write a truth table for $(A\to C)\land (B\to C)$ and compare to your truth table for $((A\lor B)\to C)$. See that they agree.

Answer (score 0):

$ (A \lor B) \Rightarrow C \equiv \neg(A \lor B) \lor C \equiv (\neg A \land \neg B) \lor C \equiv (\neg A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)
$

So, for $ (A \lor B) \Rightarrow C$ to be true, $(\neg A \lor C)$ has to be True AND $(\neg B \lor C)$ has to be True.